# How do I add a page to my app developed using Heroku?

Tags: ruby, facebook, heroku

I am new to Heroku as well as Ruby and just created a new Facebook application
using Heroku.

I created a clone of the git code in my local branch using Git Bash. After
that, I made some changes in the index.rb file: I changed the background color
of the app and deployed the updated code to git and the changes were reflected
in the application.

I created a simple HTML file in the same folder as that of the index.rb file.
Now I added a link to this HTML file, setting the `href="/samplehtmlPage.html"`
in the index.rb file. I was able to successfully deploy the code and the link
was reflected in my application, but when I clicked on it got a 'Not Found'
error.

```
//inserted the below link after the body tag in the index.rb file
<a href="/samplehtmlPage.html">click here</a>
```

Could someone please help me understand how to add an HTML file to git, add a
link in the index.rb and redirect to the new HTML file?

Comment: Don't attempt to describe everything. Instead, insert code snippets showing the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use something like:

```
git add samplehtmlPage.html
```

prior to your `git commit` and `git push`?

Without that, samplehtmlPage.html won't be part of the repo, nor will it get pushed.

Comment: I did it this time, but still I am not getting redirected to this page. The href that I have added "/sampleHTMLPage.html", is this the right way to call the page?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ruby on Rails you can use [redirect_to method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to) and replace your code (or modify your controller) with the following:

```
<%= redirect_to "/samplehtmlPage.html" %>
```